# Calculating latitude-longitude of given pixel on TIFF using numpy only

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, coordinates, latitude-longitude, numpy

I know how to calculate the latitude-longitude coordinates of a given pixel of a TIFF file using `rasterio`. Methods based on importing external functions (from within `rasterio` or `GDAL` for example) appear often, ie here: [How to speed up rasterio.transform.xy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/415062/how-to-speed-up-rasterio-transform-xy).

**How can I perform these calculations after extracting relevant values from the TIFF file using `numpy` only?**

My aim with using `numpy` only is to have a better understanding of what's going on under the hood. [Here](https://copernicus-dem-30m.s3.amazonaws.com/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N59_00_E010_00_DEM/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N59_00_E010_00_DEM.tif) is an example tiff file, a Sentinel image of Oslo area, in case you want to play around with it.