# How to export data from a WMS to TIFF using command line tools?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, wms, gdal-translate

I am able to export data from a WMS service using QGIS. I would like to be able to do the same using [`GDAL`](https://gdal.org/index.html) command line tools.

Below is a reproducible setup of my current method, which I hope to replace.

---

### QGIS setup

The Swedish Geological Survey provides this WMS: https://resource.sgu.se/service/wms/130/jorddjupsmodell

To visualize it in QGIS, I do: `Layer` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add WMS/WMTS Layer...` -> `New`, name layer as `soildepth`, provide above URL, `Connect`, then select `Jorddjup 10x10m raster, skattat jorddjup till berg (m)` from list, `Add`.

To have an example polygon, I create `testArea.geojson` in Python:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

gpd.GeoSeries(Polygon([[15, 60],[15, 60.01], [15.01, 60.01], [15.01, 60]])).to_file("testArea.geojson")
```

Adding this file to QGIS canvas too: `Layer` -> `Add Layer` -> `Add Vector Layer...`, select `testArea.geojson`, `Add`.

Result:

[image]

---

### Manual data export

Right-click on the `Jorddjup 10x10m raster, skattat jorddjup till berg (m)` layer -> `Export` -> `Save As...`.

Then:

1. Unclick "Create VRT" checkbox
2. Give a `File name`, such as `/path/to/file/soilTest.tif`
3. Select CRS: `Project CRS: EPSG:3006 - SWEREF99 TM`
4. Extent: click on `Calculate from Layer`, choose `testArea`
5. Resolution: write 10 for both `Horizontal` and `Vertical` fields

[image]

Then click `OK`. Result is as expected:

[image]

---

### How to export without QGIS?

I would like to perform the above data export using command line tools only. It is important that the final result should have projection `EPSG:3006`, it's extent should be the extent of `testArea.geojson`, and it's resolution should be 10 (m) in both directions. (Ie QGIS steps 3, 4 & 5 above.)

**How can I perform the above data export using command line tools?**

---

### Attempts using [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html)

**I.**

The suggestion of this answer is [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/443266/191643):

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff "WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=7.395557961066897,54.844017949679454,26.329613471079828,69.41367203990262" -tr 10 10 /tmp/test.tif
```

Checking the result with Python:

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open("/tmp/test.tif") as src:
    src_read = src.read()
```

`src_read` is:

```
array([[[255, 255]],
       [[252, 255]],
       [[255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

so the command needs some improvement.

**II.**

A somewhat naive attempt:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -tr 10 10 -projwin 15.0 60.01 15.01 60.0 -projwin_srs EPSG:4326 "WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=7.395557961066897,54.844017949679454,26.329613471079828,69.41367203990262" /tmp/test.tif
```

Here I use [`-projwin`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-projwin) to specify the bounding box of the area I am interested in, and [`-projwin_srs`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-projwin_srs) to specify the projection of this bounding box. The [`-tr`] is there to specify that I want 10 by 10 m pixels. This is what the [documentation says about `tr`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-tr):

> set target resolution. The values must be expressed in georeferenced units. Both must be positive values. This is mutually
> exclusive with `-outsize` and `-a_ullr`.

I don't understand how to specify the units for this.

The above command returns:

```
Input file size is 1073741824, 826238570
ERROR 5: Invalid output size: 0.501 x 0.501
```

**III.**

Instead of using geographical coordinates, can try using pixel coordinates using the [`srcwin`](https://-srcwin) option.

```
gdalinfo "WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=7.395557961066897,54.844017949679454,26.329613471079828,69.41367203990262"
```

returns:

```
Driver: WMS/OGC Web Map Service
Files: none associated
Size is 1073741824, 826238570
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ID["EPSG",6326]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8901]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (7.395557961066897,69.413672039902622)
Pixel Size = (0.000000017633713,-0.000000017633713)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   7.3955580,  69.4136720) (  7d23'44.01"E, 69d24'49.22"N)
Lower Left  (   7.3955580,  54.8440179) (  7d23'44.01"E, 54d50'38.46"N)
Upper Right (  26.3296135,  69.4136720) ( 26d19'46.61"E, 69d24'49.22"N)
Lower Right (  26.3296135,  54.8440179) ( 26d19'46.61"E, 54d50'38.46"N)
Center      (  16.8625857,  62.1288450) ( 16d51'45.31"E, 62d 7'43.84"N)
Band 1 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 536870912x413119285, 268435456x206559643, 134217728x103279821, 67108864x51639911, 33554432x25819955, 16777216x12909978, 8388608x6454989, 4194304x3227494, 2097152x1613747, 1048576x806874, 524288x403437, 262144x201718, 131072x100859, 65536x50430, 32768x25215, 16384x12607, 8192x6304, 4096x3152, 2048x1576, 1024x788
Band 2 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 536870912x413119285, 268435456x206559643, 134217728x103279821, 67108864x51639911, 33554432x25819955, 16777216x12909978, 8388608x6454989, 4194304x3227494, 2097152x1613747, 1048576x806874, 524288x403437, 262144x201718, 131072x100859, 65536x50430, 32768x25215, 16384x12607, 8192x6304, 4096x3152, 2048x1576, 1024x788
Band 3 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 536870912x413119285, 268435456x206559643, 134217728x103279821, 67108864x51639911, 33554432x25819955, 16777216x12909978, 8388608x6454989, 4194304x3227494, 2097152x1613747, 1048576x806874, 524288x403437, 262144x201718, 131072x100859, 65536x50430, 32768x25215, 16384x12607, 8192x6304, 4096x3152, 2048x1576, 1024x788
```

3rd line says: `Size is 1073741824, 826238570`. Let's extract a 500 by 500 raster from the middle (1073741824/2=536870912):

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -srcwin 536870912 536870912 500 500 "WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=7.395557961066897,54.844017949679454,26.329613471079828,69.41367203990262" /tmp/test.tif
```

Check results:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with rasterio.open("/tmp/test.tif") as src:
    src_read = src.read()

plt.imshow(np.swapaxes(src_read,0,2))
```

[image]

The output is actually a raster now, not an error, which is good.

First problem with this, is that if I change the command to:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -srcwin 100000000 100000000 500 500 "WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=7.395557961066897,54.844017949679454,26.329613471079828,69.41367203990262" /tmp/test.tif
```

I get the same result. Not good. Second, I am not able to translate the geographical coordinates of the bounding box to pixel coordinates of the WMS (I know how to do it on a raster image, see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/410739/how-to-find-a-particular-coordinate-on-a-sentinel-image-using-projtransform), but I haven't yet done pixel coordinates on WMS). I think I need to understand better the output of `gdalinfo` in order to do that.

Comment: I think the problem is the server seems to lie about it's coordinates and/or SRS. QGis is unable to import the map either.

Comment: For me QGIS does import it I think. Export also works within QGIS (first and second screenshot).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you mean by "import".

Answer (score 2):

Your data is a WMS so you need to use gdal rather than ogr but it will work, subject to the usual caveats about WMS producing a picture of the data not the actual data.

First I did a `gdalinfo` on your capabilities link:

```
gdalinfo "WMS:https://resource.sgu.se/service/wms/130/jorddjupsmodell"
```

which gave me:

```
Driver: WMS/OGC Web Map Service
Files: none associated
Size is 512, 512
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=JORDDJUPSMODELL&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=7.695846187558585,54.789792944659375,25.49767199163619,69.14432572671839
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=Jorddjupsmodell
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=7.395557961066897,54.844017949679454,26.329613471079828,69.41367203990262
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=Jorddjup 10x10m raster, skattat jorddjup till berg (m)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=JORDDJUPSMODELL_UNDERLAG&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=7.695846187558585,54.789792944659375,25.49767199163619,69.14432572671839
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=Utnyttjat underlag till jorddjupsmodellen
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.JORDARTSKARTOR&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=7.695846187558585,54.789792944659375,25.49767199163619,69.14432572671839
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=Jordartskartor
  SUBDATASET_5_NAME=WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.SPRICKZONER&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=9.573739996397562,55.15360120621276,24.754326365873002,69.08179777642593
  SUBDATASET_5_DESC=Sprickzoner
  SUBDATASET_6_NAME=WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.JORDDJUPSUPPGIFT_MINVARDE&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=9.367378360212268,55.17706082150909,25.115002345782752,68.60472942460113
  SUBDATASET_6_DESC=Jorddjupsuppgift, minimi-värde
  SUBDATASET_7_NAME=WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.JORDDJUPSUPPGIFT&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=9.166007780988775,55.17269811450856,25.38084453449201,69.1395851193348
  SUBDATASET_7_DESC=Jorddjupsuppgift
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

then I did a `gdal_translate` on the link I found in the results:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff "WMS:https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=7.395557961066897,54.844017949679454,26.329613471079828,69.41367203990262" -tr 10 10 /tmp/test.tif
```

to generate a tif, but I can't get that WMS to provide a map anywhere near Sweden.

Comment: Thank you! Gonna remove ogr2ogr references from my question not to confuse future readers. Also adding attempt relying on this answer.

Comment: Question updated :)